# Where is the error

Tags: python-3.x

Please, anyone can help me to find and fix the error?

```
x = 1089
c = int(input("Enter the number you think is")
try:
while c =! x:
if c > 1089:
        print("Very large number")
elif c < 1089:
          print("Very low number")
print("Correct Number! 1089")
except:
    print("Invalid Number!")
```

Comment: int(input("Enter the number you think is") **)**

Comment: Ok, this helped. but now idle get error "expected an intended block"

Comment: @Shazam [RTFM](https://docs.python.org/3/)

Comment: @PeterVaro will this help? I dont find the part that say about if

Comment: @Shazam well, if you carefully read the first few chapters of "Tutorials -- start here" then it will be clear, what `expected an indented block` means

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
x = 1089
c = int(input("Enter the number you think is"))# Added bracket here
try:
    while c =! x:
        if c > 1089:
            print("Very large number")
        elif c < 1089:
            print("Very low number")
    print("Correct Number! 1089")
 except:
    print("Invalid Number!")
```

Python, unlike C-based languages recognises block statements entirely by tabulation. The error is saying that you created a block but didn't put anything in it.

Also, you should change the except statement to:

```
except TypeError:
```

So it will only catch `TypeError`s thrown by the if statements, and not things like `KeyboardInterrupt` (especially when using `while` loops) and `SystemExit`